# How to initialize class with data from the internet and synchronize the class instance variables

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-async-http

I would like to apologize if this has a trivial answer but I can't seem to come up with a pattern/flow for this scenario.

I am using [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) which provides a callback for when its done with the request. I guess this is where I'm getting confused because I don't know where to use the library.

**Here is my setup:**

*DataClass.java*

```
 public class DataClass {
     String created_date = null;
     String username = null;
     String details = null;
     private static AsyncHttpClient client;

     public DataClass(String id) {
         client = new AsyncHttpClient();
         GetDataObject(id);
     }

     public void GetDataObject(String id) {
          //...build RequestParams()
          client.post(get_data_url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
              public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                 String response_string = new String(response);
                 //...parse JsonObject
                 created_data = jsonObject.getString("date");
                 username = jsonObject.getString("username");
                 details = jsonObject.getString("details");
                 // all dataClass instance variables accessed here are null.
                 Log.d("Created: ", created_data); //returns somedate
                 Log.d("Username: ", username); //returns someusername   
              }
          });
     }
 }
```

*ShowDataActivity.java*

```
 public class ShowDataActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_question);

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
         DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(id);

         // all dataClass instance variables accessed here are null.
         Log.d("Created: ", dataClass.created_data); //returns null
         Log.d("Username: ", dataClass.username); //returns null

     }
 }
```

When I put breakpoints on the instance variables assignment inside the RestClient callback, I can see that they aren't null but have the correct data in them.

I have been searching for a while and see some built-in Android libraries like [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) and [BoradcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that might help but I don't know how to use them in conjunction with [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).

**Please not the example above is not complete, but all the relevant information is there.**

Let me know if more information is needed. Thank you.

**Problem:**
When I instantiate the DataClass in ShowDataActivity my dataClass instance variables are null. I'm guessing it's because the variables are being assigned in the callback which is after I instantiate the object. Not really sure how to ask this but how can I make sure that `DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(id);` initializes with the data from the internet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You've described what you're doing, but what's the problem with it? (Particularly since your variables are being correctly set, the problem is unclear.) Also, what is `RestClient`?

Comment: Just updated the question, please note the `RestClient` changes too.

Comment: You haven't told us what you are trying to do with the data received and since it's correct, you appear to have no issues and no question!

Comment: Following your edit, you can't since the object is created before you receive your data.  To continue the chain, **why** do you need these variables to be non-null when you create the instance of the class?

Comment: Because I would like to use the data to populate Textview's and whatnot. Not really sure what you meant by that. Maybe I didn't understand you.

Comment: But surely the data in the vars is only valid once you've fetched it?  Normal practice is to show a wait cursor during loading, disable controls until loaded, not showing the activity until the data is available etc.  I'm still not clear on what you are trying to achieve.